# replace \r\n's with <br/>s

Tags: jquery, regex, json

I've successfully pulled in the JSON below however I am having an issue turning those pesky regex \r\n\r\n's into `<br/>`'s. I'm currently using the following code but it only escapes a few. I'm looking to replace ALL instances of regex including: \r\n, \r\n\r\n. The code I used before is:

```
$('<ul class="job-listing"><li class="job-position"><h2>'+post.m_positionName+'</h2></li><li class="job-description">'+post.m_description.replace('\r\n','<br />')+'</li></ul>').appendTo('body');
```

Here is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "m_id": 473644,
    "m_positionName": "Application Monitoring Software Engineer",
    "m_positionLocations": [
      {}
    ],
    "m_active": true,
    "m_description": "Job Responsibilities:\r\n\r\n-Create world class application monitoring tools and dashboards for our health care applications\r\n\r\n-Develop business rules to pro actively identify and re-mediate system-level issues before they occur.\r\n\r\n-Create business intelligence reports for internal and external use as a supplement to software products.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nJob Requirements:\r\n\r\n-BS or MS Degree in computer science or any engineering discipline.\r\n-4+ years of experience with Java (or other object-oriented programming language).\r\n-Experience in SQL, Struts, Hibernate, Spring, Eclipse, JSP, JavaScript.\r\n-Highly motivated and self-driven personality.\r\n-Excellent interpersonal and leadership skills.\r\n-A vision for the future and a desire to make a difference.\r\n-Experience with Maven, Tomcat, PostgreSql, Jasper Reports,",
    "m_postedDate": "Jun 29, 2012 9:17:19 AM",
    "m_closingDate": "Jun 29, 2013 12:00:00 AM"
  }
```

Comment: Just to be clear, does `\r\n\r\n` turn into `<br />` or `<br /><br />`?

Comment: I'd have to see how it looks but lets say for now any instance of \r\n will turn into a single <br/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
post.m_description.replace(/\r\n|\n|\r/g, '<br />');
```

Comment: Where does that code go?
Does it just replace what I wrote?
`post.m_description.replace('\r\n','<br />')+'</li></ul>')`

Comment: @user1324700 Yes the replace there should be changed to the global regex that I have provided in my answer. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
replace(/\r\n/, '<br/>')
```

regular expressions in JS don't need to be encapsulated by quotes